# Distribution Provisioning Problems

Tags: iphone, distribution

I had an app that I finally got finalized and am ready to post it to the App Store so I started the amazingly awful process...

I have been developing on my laptop, testing on my device, and having no issues with my development certificate and provisioning.

I ended up having to rename my project (Project->rename for anyone who needs to know).  I then rebuilt my project, tested it out on my devices and all is ok.

I went online and created my AppID for the project and then created my App Dist Profile.  I Downloaded it and dragged it into XCode's organizer.  I immediately see "A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain."  I've checked my certificates and double checked that I created the right AppID, profile, etc.. What could possibly cause this?

Am I the only one that is constantly blown away at the amount of work that it takes to actually get ON the app store once the app is done?  Anyone else kind of miss the J2ME days (minus the fee's, J-verified, and VeriSign crap.. haha)

Thanks,

-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I *think* because I was around before XCode managed the provisioning stuff that my old certificate was causing issues with the new distribution certificates.  I just erased all my keys, certificates, profiles and started over.

In order I did this:

1) Removed all keys
2) Revoked the certificates on both development and distribution
3) Removed all profiles
4) Created a new Cert Request
5) Downloaded and installed both distribution and development certs
6) Created profiles
7) Installed everything.
8) Opened XCode and went to organizer, profiles, and hit refresh to update my team provisioning profile

It all finally works.

Wow..

Answer (score 0):

Have you created and downloaded the Distribution (not Developer) certificate? Did you also install the WWDR certificate (if needed)?

Comment: Yes I did get a Dist profile and not the regular developer profile.  That is the certificate that is giving me problems.  I did install the WWDR awhile ago and just checked again.  any other ideas?